# debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to connect my ubuntu server with ssh. The lines of code that are uncommented in my `sshd_config` are below:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

My operating system is Mac and I've activated the `remote login` and `remote management` options in settings.
when I want to connect server with `ssh -p 22 root@IP` I get the below error:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you put your public key into the authorized_keys on server side?

Comment: How can I put the public key into the server side when I don't have access?

Comment: If you do not have access, you have to ask an administrator

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su], [unix.se], or [ubuntu.se]. When you do, you should indicate which key file you are expecting ssh to use to authenticate, and describe what you did to set the key up on the remote server.